# Open native Snapchat App from my Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url-scheme, snapchat

I'd like to implement the native Snapchat App into my iOS Application. I've already done that with Facebook and Twitter by using the URL Schemes. But I weren't able to find such thing for Snapchat.

I found something to open Snapchat in Safari "see it below below", but i need the scheme itself, thanks in advance.

```
 https://www.snapchat.com/add/ProfileName
```

Comment: did you tried to add snapchat to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as @Kirualex said

Answer (score 4):

```
    let username = "USERNAME"
    let appURL = URL(string: "snapchat://add/\(username)")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL) {
        application.open(appURL)

    } else {
        // if Snapchat app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        let webURL = URL(string: "https://www.snapchat.com/add/\(username)")!
        application.open(webURL)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to add a specific user assuming the app is already installed:

```
NSURL *snapchatURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.snapchat.com/add/username"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:snapchatURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:snapchatURL];
}
```

Replace username with the desired user's name

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing it like this:

```
NSURL *snapchatURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"snapchat://app"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:snapchatURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:snapchatURL];
}
```

Also added snapchat to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in plist.

Comment: it's working but can i make it ask to add specific profile ? 

like ( do you want to add username ) ?